# Convert JSON containing `\u####` to Unicode string

Tags: c#, unicode

I would need some help for a string conversion from unicode (`\u03a9\u039c\u0395\u0393\u0391`) to normal string (`ΩΜΕΓΑ`).
I made a function that theoretically should work but it doesn't work instead. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.
I receive json data with `webclient.DownloadString`:

```
{"id": "94401626335", "username": "\u03a9\u039c\u0395\u0393\u0391"}
```

I get the `\u03a9\u039c\u0395\u0393\u0391` and send it to the function:

```
DecodeFromUtf8(username)

public string DecodeFromUtf8(string utf8String)
        {
            try
            {
                var output = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(utf8String);
                return output;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return utf8String;
            }
        }
```

the function always returns me: `\u03a9\u039c\u0395\u0393\u0391`
and not: `ΩΜΕΓΑ`
Why?

i can't use external libraries like system.text.json

Thanks

Comment: whats in UTF8 string?

Comment: It looks like the response is just JSON - so use a JSON parser to handle it, and it should perform the decoding for you. (I don't see any sign of HTML, so you shouldn't use HtmlDecode. Note that HTML uses a different way of performing escaping, which is presumably why it's not working...)

Comment: `WebUtility.HtmlDecode` does HTML decoding, not JSON decoding.

Comment: Fundamentally, you shouldn't try to deal with the JSON as a plain string. *Always* use a JSON library to handle it. (There are other escape sequences you'd need to handle, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

use a json deserializer , let it do the work

```
  public class Ooo {
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
  }

    var json = @"{""id"": ""94401626335"", ""username"": ""\u03a9\u039c\u0395\u0393\u0391""}";
    var ooo = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Ooo>(json) ;
    Console.WriteLine("string = " + ooo.username);
}
```

gives (my console has a glyph misssing, but its show correctly in the debugger)

[image]

Comment: This works fine, thanks
But I wanted to avoid libraries outside the file

Comment: @Mcdriven83 so why did you try `WebUtility.HtmlDecode` ? System.Text.Json is a built in library of .net just like WebUtility